# How to increase Shadow DOM speficity

Tags: angular, sass, css-selectors

In my `component.scss` file I have this style that overrides the global style from `styles.scss`:

```
.nb-theme-cosmic ng2-smart-table table tr td {
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Because of the Shadow DOM the resulting CSS selector is this:

```
[_nghost-frv-c404] table tr td{
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

It is less specific than the global selector. How can I increase the shadow dom speficity?

Comment: I guess it depends on the current specificity the global style sets (since you need higher specificity), can add \ create a stackblitz of the global style?

Comment: You really can’t make the shadow dom selector more specific as that hierarchy starts at the component (which is the idea I guess). The only solution seems to be to make your other selectors less specific..?

Comment: @Moshezauros The selector inside the `component.scss` is the same as the global selector, I should be chosen because it appears later. But shadow dom modifies it and it loses specificity.

Comment: @MikeOne The global style I'm trying to modify is from a theme installed with npm. I could modify base CSS but it will be replaced if packages are installed again.

Comment: Hmm.. that’s a problem indeed. Does it actually make sense to have your component as shadow dom if you’re planning to style it globally anyway?